# Adding hyperlink to contents of vaadin grid cell data

Tags: vaadin-grid

Is it possible to have an inline hyperlink inside the text of a vaadin grid cell?  For example, something like:

```
For more information please visit our website at <a href="#">OurWebsite.com</a>
```

where "OurWebsite.com" is a link

I cannot have a dedicated cell for this link info - it has to live inside plain old text

I tried inserting HTML into my data but of course it just rendered as plain old text, not a hyperlink

We are using vaadin-grid v2 as part of our JavaScript Polymer web app. the HTML looks something like:

```
<vaadin-grid id='notesGrid' items={{notes}}>
```

where notes is an array of text data.

Comment: Could share more information. "vaadin-grid" gives a hint that you are using web component in JavaScript/TypeScript project? Is this true? Which version of the component you use. Or do you use Vaadin Flow, and if yes, which version. Can you share code how you setup your Grid?

Comment: we are using vaadin-grid v2 as part of our JavaScript Polymer web app.
the HTML looks something like:

<vaadin-grid id='notesGrid' items={{notes}}>

where notes is an array of text data.

Answer (score 1):

That is fairly old version `vaadin-grid`, which uses the old approach of using templates for rendering custom content in the cell. Assuming that your hyperlink is in property `link` in your note, it could look like this:

```
  <vaadin-grid items="[[notes]]">

    <vaadin-grid-column>
      <template class="header">Link</template>
      <template><a href="[[item.link]]"></template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>

  </vaadin-grid>
```